# Does distance correlation work for count data?

Tags: count-data, distance-covariance

I'm considering using partial distance correlation to test for conditional independence in multivariate count data. However, I haven't been able to find any good sources that discuss whether (partial) distance correlation works well for count data. So, my question is twofold:

- Does (partial) distance correlation work for count data?
- If so, does it work well? In other words, how well would a conditional independence test based on partial distance correlation work compared to a conditional independence test based on conditional mutual information?